# Two ways to exclude modules in Gradle

Tags: gradle

Which is the difference between excluding a module in `configurations.compile` block:

```
configurations.compile {
    exclude module: 'spring-core'
}
```

and doing it in `dependencies` block?

```
compile('org.simpleframework:simple-xml:2.7.+') {
    exclude module: 'stax'
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second exclude applies to `simple-xml` alone, while the first exclude applies to *all* dependencies in the `compile` scope.